# Mysql database structure for realestate directory

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I really need help to make a decision.

I'm working on a real estate online directory.
People can add their property in several categories like apartment, land, shop ... and each category has its features that some of them are shared between categories like City but some others are unique or shared between 2 or 3 categories like "number of rooms".

So i have three solution :

- keep shared features in one table and put others in an other table in meta_key - meta_value format like tagging system.(seem reasonable)
- Put all features in one table.(dirty)
- Put each category in separate table (this is worst idea).

The site will serve too many searches. but most of them are based on shared features.
which solution looks better?

Comment: Could you please make a better distinction between property as in "real estate property" versus property as in "attribute (of a real estate property)"?

Comment: property is an item in our system like my house, my shop and so.
but properties are like "number of rooms","has parking", "heating system" and ...

Comment: Exactly. You are using the same term for different things. That makes your question unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just create a table of the properties and then tie them together in a table like so:

Categoryid | PropertyID

Also making both columns a composite unique identifier will prevent from duplicate occuring with the table.  This allows you to create unlimited properties and assign them to any category.

Comment: What's the purpose of `id` here?

Comment: It is generally a good idea to have a unique row identifier or a primary key.

Comment: Does `CategoryID, PropertyID` not identify the row uniquely?

Comment: @ObieMD5 Having a surrogate key has [pros and cons](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info), like almost everything in engineering. Just saying "it is generally a good idea" might leave the reader unaware of cons.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - It does but I guess you could get rid of the id field and make a composite key of the two so that it will prevent duplicate entries.

Comment: @Branko - You are correct, I should not of put that because it is senario dependent.

Comment: because i'm aware that searching will be slow because if someone search for "number of rooms" > 2 it will search all properties with meta_key="number of rooms".

Comment: @Milad Ray - I can only think to query the table above to filter down your categories before querying against the properties.

Comment: @ObieMD5 ya i think the best solution is putting non-shared properties in separate table with item_id|Category_id|meta_key|meta_value fields.

Comment: To my comment above the reference to properties was meant the real estate properties (condo, house, etc.)

Comment: @ObieMD5 categories are not my problem. my problem is non-shared  features like "number of rooms" because a land doesn't need this but an apartment needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33284/discussion-between-obiemd5-and-milad-rey)